# ReviewDog Secrets Not Detecting TF Secrets

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have a secret in my main.tf file

```
provider "github" {
  token = "jAMQrk2fwYNs" # demo secret - not real don't worry
  organization = "PersonalProjects"
}
```

My `.github/workflows/secret-scanning.yml` file looks like the following

```
name: Run detect-secrets with reviewdog
run-name: Detect Secrets
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  secrets-check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: check for secrets
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run detect-secrets with reviewdog
        uses: reviewdog/action-detect-secrets@v0.11.5
```

Why doesn't my github action fail?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reviewdog/action-detect-secrets` runs `detect-secrets` (https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets) under the hood.

After installing `detect-secrets`, you can check the list of plugins it uses:

```bash
$ detect-secrets --version
1.4.0

$ detect-secrets scan --list-all-plugins
ArtifactoryDetector
AWSKeyDetector
AzureStorageKeyDetector
BasicAuthDetector
CloudantDetector
DiscordBotTokenDetector
GitHubTokenDetector
Base64HighEntropyString
HexHighEntropyString
IbmCloudIamDetector
IbmCosHmacDetector
JwtTokenDetector
KeywordDetector
MailchimpDetector
NpmDetector
PrivateKeyDetector
SendGridDetector
SlackDetector
SoftlayerDetector
SquareOAuthDetector
StripeDetector
TwilioKeyDetector
```

For your scenario, `GitHubTokenDetector` is being used.

You can look at its implementation [here](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets/blob/master/detect_secrets/plugins/github_token.py):

```py
# ...

class GitHubTokenDetector(RegexBasedDetector):
    """Scans for GitHub tokens."""
    secret_type = 'GitHub Token'

    denylist = [
        # ref. https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/
        re.compile(r'(ghp|gho|ghu|ghs|ghr)_[A-Za-z0-9_]{36}'),
    ]
```

You can observe the regex being used here. For detection, the token should start with these prefixes and its total length should be 40 characters.

- `ghp` for GitHub personal access tokens
- `gho` for OAuth access tokens
- `ghu` for GitHub user-to-server tokens
- `ghs` for GitHub server-to-server tokens
- `ghr` for refresh tokens

See [Behind GitHub’s new authentication token formats](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/) for more details.

---

As an example, I used this sample `main.tf` file with multiple dummy tokens (generated using `base64` and `sha1sum` utilities; also edited to add some random alphabets):

```
provider "github" {
  token1 = "ghp_MabcfMTIzZHVtbXl0b2tlbjEyMzEyMzEyMwo="
  token2 = "ghr_MTIabceIzZHVtbXl0b2tlbjEyMzEyMzEyMwo="
  token3 = "accf30ed92f4c139e9ea2d255e4c8606fbca2651"
}
```

Here's the output (only the `results` JSON subobject):

```bash
$ detect-secrets scan --all-files | jq '.results'
{
  "main.tf": [
    {
      "type": "GitHub Token",
      "filename": "main.tf",
      "hashed_secret": "e175c6f5f2a92e8623bd9a4820edb4e8c1b0fd10",
      "is_verified": false,
      "line_number": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "GitHub Token",
      "filename": "main.tf",
      "hashed_secret": "81c9f106f028bebcb41c013254854d7c6a1c4319",
      "is_verified": false,
      "line_number": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "Hex High Entropy String",
      "filename": "main.tf",
      "hashed_secret": "6f27f9643e7fd0b969a1c77ee3b0c23351d039c4",
      "is_verified": false,
      "line_number": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

So, you need to provide tokens that fulfill the detection criteria.

Comment: @stk1234: You're welcome! In addition, there's entropy involved also. It's discussed in the linked article. If you run `detect-secrets scan --help`, you'll see its default values. As of now, with version `1.4.0`, the help shows `--base64-limit` (default `4.5`) and `--hex-limit` (default `3.0`). You may configure it according to your use case.